# Download video from URL and generate thumbnail (Android)

Tags: android, video, thumbnails

I'm quite new to Android development and I've been trying to generate a thumbnail from a video url for my Android app. I tried every "solution" out there that doesn't require me to download the video first or any libraries.

So I decided to download the video and then get the thumbnail once I have the video locally...

My question is how do I download the video temporarily so that I can use the `ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail` method and once I have the thumbnail, delete the video from localstorage?

Thanks.

Comment: I think its a very bad idea to download the video only to get `Thumbnail`.

Comment: yeah but I can't find a way without doing so, except for the FFMPEG library which I don't want to install unless that is the only way possible.